How to read this old French speed gauge?
Vitesses au Sol is ground speed, and Vitesses Vrais is true air speed, but

what is the backward scale 450 to 750 for?
how does one read altitude?
the bendy wire looks like it's probably related to the true airspeed markings, but how?
why did this elegant design not catch on?

In short, how is it to be read as its arms and displays rotate?

Source

Source
This second one is similar but oddly the spiral is reversed. A US Patent for this instrument (1919) is available and may provide clues to those attuned to patent descriptions.

Wow. That is a beautiful instrument.

Bendy wire of the top one seems the wrong way around. Bottom one makes way more sense. Poor "restauration" I'd guess?

Regarding why it didn't catch on, there might be a clue in a page @mins links to, which describes the device as 17cm in diameter. Huge!

Adding to @Camille's good answer.

This instrument combines different airspeed and altitude indications:

Airspeeds in the top half use two scales: The outer vitesses au sol scale and a scale with curved marks vitesses vraies close to the center. Both scales are likely km/h considering the era, less likely knots. (The actual unit has no influence on the instrument).

Altitudes in the bottom half: The outer pressions barométriques, static pressure in mmHg, a fixed scale, and inner altitudes, a moving scale in meters. This scale can be rotated using a screw or a knob. Altitude 0 m would be aligned with the local QNH (760 mmHg for the standard pressure). This is similar to the setting of a modern altimeter using the Kollsman window.


My understanding is airspeed is measured using the dynamic pressure from a pitot tube, and altitude is measured using the static pressure from a static port, thus the instrument basically combines an airspeed indicator with an altimeter. However the instrument is also a mechanical calculator producing a correction factor and applying it to the dynamic pressure from the pitot to get the true airspeed (TAS).
It was invented by Maurice Dugit-Gros ca. 1919 and manufactured by SIAM. The patent applies to a broader scope: A method and apparatus for the mechanical calculation and display of functions depending on non-linear factors. This instrument is indeed an application of this patent to calculate and display the true airspeed.
About TAS and the upper outer scale vitesses au sol
Airspeed value is often a mapping of the dynamic pressure value measured with a pitot tube. Airspeed "calculated" this way is the indicated airspeed (IAS). The pitot pressure is however subject to several errors, the largest being related to its placement on the aircraft and the aircraft own orientation relative to the airflow.
Other airspeeds are derived from IAS: Removing pitot errors from IAS gives the calibrated airspeed (CAS); Removing errors associated with air compressibility from CAS gives the equivalent airspeed (EAS); Removing errors associated with the variation of air density with altitude from EAS gives the true airspeed (TAS). See airspeed calculator and conversion.
Ground speed (GS) and airspeeds are related by wind speed. GS is the vector sum of the aircraft speed in the air mass and the air mass speed relative to the ground (i.e. wind). In no wind condition, the two speeds are equal (GS is still affected by the errors associated with the chosen airspeed).
In the instrument shown two types of speeds are displayed: vitesse vraie and vitesse au sol, which are literally translated as true speed and ground speed.

The former is likely TAS. The red straight hand of the top half sweeps both the TAS scale and the outer scale. This hand is driven by the pitot dynamic pressure, but some correction is applied in the mechanics behind the instrument plate, also using a scale with curved marks and a spiral hand. This complex setting is required to perform the mechanical calculation of the TAS which is a non-linear function.

The latter vitesse au sol (ground speed) is more difficult to interpret: Displaying GS appears curious for this era. GS calculation implies wind speed knowledge, or another mean for speed measurement, not based on pitot data.
Both @Kenn Sebesta and @Sanchises spotted this strangeness, as well as @Camille Goudeseune in his answer. Warned by their inputs, I've reworked my answer. I'm also convinced the scale is not a GS scale in spite of the name and I'm also inclined to think it should be IAS, the information given by a basic airspeed indicator.
The reason the inventor used GS instead of IAS might be corresponding definitions didn't exist ca. 1920, the full model of airspeed measurement being still to establish. This should be digged further, but IAS appears much more plausible than GS.


Bottom altimeter
The white hand with a double black head sweeps over a scale of atmospheric pressures (pressions barométriques), it is driven by the static pressure from a static port.
The leftmost indication is 780 mmHg. The mean sea level (MSL) pressure is 760 mmHg and pressure continues to decrease with altitude. (On the picture I used below the 750 mark is slightly offset.)
A corresponding altitude scale is aligned with the static pressure scale. The altitude mark 0 m must be aligned with the pressure at MSL (the QNH) or 760 mmHg (the QNE) if the QNH is unknown.
TAS reading
The white altimeter hand has a red spiral extension which sweeps the TAS scale of the upper half. As we saw, TAS must correct for density variation with static pressure. So TAS must be mechanically calculated using both the dynamic pressure (red straight hand of the top half) and static pressure (red spiral hand fixed to the altimeter hand).
The TAS value is read at the intersection of these two red hands.
Example
Let's take an example where the straight red hand indicates 160 on the IAS (outer) scale, and the white hand indicates 1524 m (5000 ft) on the bottom altitude scale:

Readings are:

IAS = 160 (likely km/h), under the orange straight hand.

TAS = 170 (same unit as IAS), at the intersection of the orange and the blue spiral hands, over the scale with curved marks.

Static pressure = 630 mmHg (840 hPa, 24.8 inHg), blue hand over outer scale.

QNH = 749 mmHg (999 hPa, 29.49 inHg). Set with the knob.

Altitude = 1524 m, bottom blue hand over inner scale.


With the white altimeter hand in the original position of the photo (100 m) and the IAS still equal to 160, the TAS reading is different. The intersection of the orange hand and the red spiral hand gives a TAS of 160. The equality TAS and IAS results from the fact compressibility and density errors are about null near MSL.
You can check other IAS (orange lines) with the IAS-TAS mapping for 5 000 ft in this question: What is the relation between IAS and TAS at a constant altitude? It's actually the CAS-TAS mapping, but we can assume IAS ≈ CAS given the low IAS (low compressibility) and the precision of the instrument.

Spiral hand direction

This second one is similar but oddly the spiral is reversed.

On the first photo, the spiral hand has been assembled the wrong way: When altitude increases (CCW rotation) TAS must also increase. As it is mounted, TAS decreases. On the second photo, the spiral hand is in the correct position.
Forgotten instrument

why did this elegant design not catch on?

Likely because IAS is sufficient for flying at moderate speeds, and there are dedicated electronic devices for TAS and Mach for faster aircraft.
Such instruments were not uncommon before the advent of analog computers. It is little-known but France has been a pioneer for aviation and aviation instruments. The basic airspeed indicator (ASI) was invented in France  (locally this instrument is known by the name of its inventor, a Badin).
SIAM (which manufactured the Dugit-Gros instrument) and SFIM were specialized in manufacturing complex instruments. Some, military oriented, were later used on the Dassault Mirage series (e.g. the Bézu 3D attitude indicator, another Maurice), other, civil-oriented, were later used on Concorde.
Regarding information about older instruments, there is a historical document from Jean Carpentier, Un demi-siècle d'aéronautique en France, unfortunately only in French.

I'm not sure that <> is in fact "ground speed" here. Looking at https://www.comptoir-aviation.com/le_comptoir_de_laviation/2017/images/171212_indicateur-Dugit_02.jpg, it's pretty clear that for a given <> true airspeed varies as a function of the spiral dial. This would point toward this being IAS, and perhaps <> might have meant in 1919 the speed of the vehicle at sea level on an STP day. (And FWIW, the patent doesn't answer this question.)

Thanks, that's a very helpful diagram. Still, the outer dial doesn't look like windless ground speed, which would equal TAS. (Since TAS is defined as the speed moving relative to the air mass, and if the air mass isn't moving than that equates the (modern?) definition of ground speed). Perhaps there's a typo when you say Ground speed (GS) without wind (TAS at mean seal level (MSL))?

I agree with Kenn. I don't think "Vitesse au sol" means Ground Speed as known in English, but something like "equivalent airspeed as if you were flying close to the ground" - known as Equivalent Airspeed in English.

@mins I think we are, rereading your answer. I think the confusion comes from your first bulleted point which is ambiguous and is being interpreted as current TAS which is not TAS as if the plane were at ground level. I have made an edit which I think reflects this better, feel free to revert if this isn't to your liking.

@KennSebesta and Sanchises: Your inputs are meaningful, I reworked my answer to take your suggestions into account, I opted for IAS, but I agree it could be EAS too. Thanks to both of you.

@mins great work, much better than my version!

For a start:
The bottom half's scale 750 ... 450 is barometric pressure in mm Hg.  Twirl the thumbscrew at right to calibrate the rotating altitude scale 0 ... 4000 (metres) to match the current mm Hg at ground level.  Twirl it until 0 feet matches current conditions.  Then the needle that shows barometric pressure gives you altitude.  That may be the needle reading 450 mm Hg in this photo.
The other needle then reads roughly zero airspeed.  The spiral from its tip can't match true to indicated airspeed (how would 40 match 260?).  The airspeed needle then points to both the true and (approximate) indicated airspeeds.  What are the spiral's tips really attached to, the needle(s), or the faceplate?

I bet the units are metric.
